# JAVA NIO Server - NOT receiving client blank message / partial message

Tags: java, server, nio

I built a server and client using NIO package with server socket channel and socket channel. The basic setup works. but when I try to move my code handling each connection in a separate thread using executor service I start getting weird errors where I am getting partial message or sometimes blank messages.

This is my code where am I passing my selection key to a thread with executor service

```
private void readAndRespond(SelectionKey selectionKey) {
    this.executorService.submit(new Worker(selectionKey));
}

private class Worker implements Runnable {
    private SelectionKey selectionKey;

    private Worker(SelectionKey selectionKey) {
        this.selectionKey = selectionKey;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        SocketChannel socketChannel;
        ArrayList<ByteBuffer> buffers;
        String data, reply;
        ByteBuffer responseBuffer;

        socketChannel = (SocketChannel) selectionKey.channel();

        try {
            buffers = this.readRequest(socketChannel);
            data = this.extractData(buffers);

            if (!data.isEmpty()) {
                reply = responseManager.reply(data);
                responseBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(reply.getBytes());
                socketChannel.write(responseBuffer);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to process response " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private ArrayList<ByteBuffer> readRequest(SocketChannel socketChannel) throws IOException {
        int counter;
        ByteBuffer current;
        ArrayList<ByteBuffer> buffers;

        counter = 2;
        buffers = new ArrayList<>();
        current = ByteBuffer.allocate(minBuffer);
        buffers.add(current);

        while (socketChannel.read(current) > 0) {
            if (!current.hasRemaining()) {
                current = ByteBuffer.allocate(minBuffer * 2 * counter);
                buffers.add(current);
                counter++;
            }
        }

        return buffers;
    }

    private String extractData(ArrayList<ByteBuffer> buffers) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder;

        stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for(ByteBuffer buffer : buffers) {
            stringBuilder.append(new String(buffer.array(), "UTF-8"));
        }

        return stringBuilder.toString().trim();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to add this before handing off to thread for reading

```
selectionKey.interestOps( selectionKey.interestOps() & ~SelectionKey.OP_READ );
```